# ¿Como puedo hacer que el JFrame en Java se cierre al dejar de usarlo por cierto tiempo?

Tags: java, java-swing

me ayudarían que mi formulario en JFrame se cierre en 5 segundos solo cuando el programa esta inactivo. Y que el programa se siga ejecutando normal cuando estoy escribiendo en un JTextField, dando clic al botón, etc.

No domino el tema de timer y estoy haciendo una demora al presionar el botón cada vez.
[image: Captura-de-pantalla-2022-10-07-120722.png]

Formulario:

```
package com.mycompany.prueba;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.Timer;
public class frmConTimer extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public Timer  tiempo;
        
public frmConTimer() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    tiempo=new Timer(5000, null);
    tiempo.start();
    tiempo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cerrar();
        }
    });
}
private void cerrar(){
        dispose();
    }
    private void retrasoCerrar(){
        tiempo.setInitialDelay(5000);
        tiempo.start();
    }

 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        tiempo.stop();
        retrasoCerrar();
    }
```

Comment: quizas tendrias que investigar cuando pierdan el foco los elementos del jframe, recien busque y existen eventos de foco en java, focuslistener.

Comment: ¿Qué considerar como actividad? En cada uno de esos eventos tendrías que reiniciar el temporizador.

Answer (score 0):

Podes utilizar 'Java.util.Timer' o 'tava.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPooExecutor'

Un ejemplo usando 'Timer':

```
// Seteo el tiempo en el que el JFrame debería cerrarse (en milisegundos)
int delay = 10000;

// Creo el Timer y agendo una tarea que cierre el JFrame

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    frame.dispose();
  }
}, delay);
```

También podes usar 'ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor':

```
// Seteo el tiempo en el que el JFrame debería cerrarse (en milisegundos)

int delay = 10000;

// Creo un ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor y agendo una tarea que cierre JFrame 

ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new 
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    frame.dispose();
  }
}, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```